# Botframework - resize bot chat in width

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

Is it possible to resize the width of the chat for botframework ? Currently I'm testing on a emulator. Basically I want make my bot chat wider to the right. As you can see in the picture, the chat width remain the same despite me increasing the size of the columns, add more columns, and so on. Currently using adaptive card. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the iframe embed, you can edit the width of the iframe HTML element by adding the style in-line:

```
<div id="bot">
<iframe src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/..." 
        style="height: 600px; width: 500px; resize: both;">
</iframe>
```

Alternatively, if you want greater control you can edit the styling directly to the Web Chat source code -

[Customizing Web Chat](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/11/customize-web-chat-websites/)