# Button alignment in Adaptive cards

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I was wondering if there is a way to control alignment of buttons in Adaptive card in Bot Emulator.

I tried the same code in the emulator, and the Microsoft Visualizer, but they render differently. Here are the images: [Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkLY7.jpg) [Visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b92Q.jpg)

Here's the code I've used:

```
{
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "content": {
            '$schema': 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
            'version': '1.0',
            'type': 'AdaptiveCard',
            'body': [
            {
                'type': 'TextBlock',
                'text': 'Meeting Title',
                'weight': 'bolder'
            },
            {
                'type': 'TextBlock',
                'text': 'Location',
                'separator': true,
                'isSubtle': true,
                'size': 'small'
            },
            {
                'type': 'TextBlock',
                'text': 'Location',
                'spacing': 'none'
            },
            {
                'type': 'TextBlock',
                'text': 'Organizer',
                'separator': true,
                'isSubtle': true,
                'size': 'small'
            },
            {
                'type': 'TextBlock',
                'text': 'Organizer Name',
                'spacing': 'none'
            },
            {
                'type': 'TextBlock',
                'text': 'Start Time',
                'separator': true,
                'isSubtle': true,
                'size': 'small'
            },
            {
                'type': 'ColumnSet',
                'spacing': 'none',
                'columns': [
                {
                    'type': 'Column',
                    'width': 'auto',
                    'items': [
                    {
                        'type': 'TextBlock',
                        'text': '05:00 PM',
                        'isSubtle': false,
                        'weight': 'bolder'
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'type': 'Column',
                    'width': 'auto',
                    'items': [
                    {
                        'type': 'TextBlock',
                        'text': 'May 21'
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'type': 'Column',
                    'width': 'auto',
                    'items': [
                    {
                        'type': 'TextBlock',
                        'text': '2017',
                        'isSubtle': true,
                        'weight': 'bolder'
                    }
                    ]
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                'type': 'TextBlock',
                'text': 'End Time',
                'separator': true,
                'isSubtle': true,
                'size': 'small'
            },
            {
                'type': 'ColumnSet',
                'spacing': 'none',
                'columns': [
                {
                    'type': 'Column',
                    'width': 'auto',
                    'items': [
                    {
                        'type': 'TextBlock',
                        'text': '05:30 PM',
                        'isSubtle': false,
                        'weight': 'bolder'
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'type': 'Column',
                    'width': 'auto',
                    'items': [
                    {
                        'type': 'TextBlock',
                        'text': 'May 21'
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'type': 'Column',
                    'width': 'auto',
                    'items': [
                    {
                        'type': 'TextBlock',
                        'text': '2017',
                        'isSubtle': true,
                        'weight': 'bolder'
                    }
                    ]
                }

                ]
            }
            ],
            'actions': [
            {
                'type': 'Action.Submit',
                'title': 'Accept',
                'data':{
                    'accept': true
                }
            },
            {
                'type': 'Action.Submit',
                'title': 'Decline',
                'data':{
                    'accept': false
                }
            }
            ]
      }
    }
```

As seen, the buttons are aligned horizontally in the emulator, and next to each other in the visualizer. Is there a way to modify the height and width of the buttons, as well as the way they are aligned?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293477/botframework-resize-bot-chat-in-width

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there is a way to control alignment of buttons in
>   Adaptive card in Bot Emulator.

Short answer is "No". You cannot modify the render of components in the Emulator.

Long answer is: Bot Framework Emulator is open-source, so you can try to modify and run locally your custom emulator. But I'm not sure that making a custom render on the emulator is very useful for real projects, as they will not run on the emulator.

Emulator sources are located here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [Hostconfig](https://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/index.html?hostApp=Bot%20Framework%20WebChat) with Adaptive cards, try using that. Have shared the editor tool link.